# How can I pull off an INSERT, SELECT, JOIN, and CAST query with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, sql-insert

I have been trying to set up a test database but I keep running into issues with pulling in the data from its normalized form.

Below is the latest version of the SQL query I've been working on.

```
INSERT INTO TestData.dbo.Info (Name,Did)
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name, b.Did
FROM StageDB.dbo.MockData a INNER JOIN Testdata.dbo.Dinfo b
ON a.Name = CAST(b.Did as varchar(10))
```

The output I get is the following:

> (0 row(s) affected)

I've been trying to monkey around with it on my own but can't seem to make it work the way I want to.

My objective here is to pull data (the primary key from a table with data already in my database, Did from TestData.dbo.Dinfo that is of int type) and merge it with data from my staging table (a particular column from the table in the staging database, StageDB.dbo.MockData, Name of type varchar(10)), then inserting into a new table on my main database. The database table I'm trying to put these things into is all set up with the correct fields and types (primary key column, auto generated as rows are added, Name column that is varchar(10), and Did column that is int).

EDIT: Table Definitions, Sample Data, Desired Result

Destination Table:

TestData.dbo.Info

Columns: Iid (int, primary key of table set to auto increment as new records are added), Name (varchar(10)), Did (int, foreign key from TestData.dbo.Dinfo).

StageDB.dbo.MockData

Columns: Many columns exist in this table that are not relevant to what I am trying to pull off. The only one I am interested in is the column containing names that I want to tie together with information from the Dinfo table. Name (nvarchar(255),null).

TestData.dbo.Dinfo

Columns: Did (int, primary key), Donor (varchar(20)).

Sample of Data

From Dinfo:

```
Did        Donor 
01         Howard L
```

From MockData:

```
Name
Smith J
```

Desired Results

```
Iid      Name      Did
01       Smith J   01
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. I would really like it if someone can show me the correct SQL syntax for this as I think it may just be a matter of writing it correctly. Additionally, any tips or websites that can help me learn more SQL would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `a.Name = b.Dib`.is your problem. `a.Name` in implicitly cast to an `int` in that `JOIN`. And, as you've already seen `'CA123'` can't be converted to an `int`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: What are you trying to do with that WHERE clause?

Comment: @TabAlleman I suspect it's an even worse (non-SARGable) form of when people do silly things like `WHERE 1=1;`, so that they have a (pointless) `WHERE` clause they can easily add to later.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for the pointers and you're right about the WHERE clause lol

Comment: I very strongly suggest getting rid of that `WHERE`clause then; It could ruin your query's performance.

Comment: @Larnu I've adjust my code, error is gone but the data isn't inserting >.<

Comment: What is the logic for the desired results from your sample data?  The name "Smith J" doesn't tie in any way to the row in `Dinfo`, and where did the `Iid` come from?

Comment: @TabAlleman The logic is this; Dinfo table has the names of different donors and the Info table will tie the donor to the person receiving the donation (scholarship). Iid is that table's primary key that is generated from the Name and Did combination. The data now is jumbled together in one big Access table and I'm attempting normalize it.

Comment: Ok, but HOW does the info table tie the donor to the person receiving the scholarship?

Comment: @TabAlleman I apologize in advance if I'm not making it clear, or even if it seems like I don't know what I'm doing (not far from the truth to be honest) but, the data from the Access table contains a row for each individual. I know the things are related based off of how they sit in the Access table. As far as how the info table tie them together, I would respond by saying that they are tied together by the Name and Did, which is being done manually for now (while I set up the whole database with just the one record from the original table. Does that help?

Comment: No I'm sorry, your question is still not clear.   Perhaps following the instructions in this blog -- to the letter!! -- would help:   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/   I think you need to forget what you think you know about what is relevent and not in your tables, and show us everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
ON a.Name = b.Did
```

To this:

```
ON a.Name = CAST(b.Did as varchar(10))
```

I suspect there's a lot more wrong with your query in terms of getting the results you want, but this should fix your error.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in the CAST.

Comment: @TabAlleman You were right. It did fix the error but did not provide the results I wanted. It just returned the 0 row(s) affected message. I'm not sure why it is not working though. You had stated that there may be more wrong with my query; what looks off to you? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LionOrion the WHERE clause and the ON clause both look off to me.  It's unusual to JOIN on a name=ID.  Usually it's either ID=ID, or name=name.  The where clause is basically useless, like saying WHERE 1=1.  If you edit your question and add your table definitions, sample data and desired result, I could probably give you a definitive solution.

Comment: @TabAlleman I've made the edits. Hopefully they are what you were looking for in order to be able to help. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out where the error is occurring.  There are three possibilities:

1. mockdata.name is a string and NInfo.data is an integer
2. dinfo.did is a string and NInfo.did is an integer
3. mockdata.name is a string and dinfo.did is an integer (or vice versa)

Based on the naming conventions, the third is the most likely.  When a number is compared to a string, the string is converted to a number. However, you need to be careful whenever you use implicit type conversions.

If the third option, then you can convert the integer to a string (as other answers propose).  However, I would ask why you are doing such a comparison.

Comment: The third option is indeed correct. I am trying to normalize some data in addition to learning more SQL. The data can be pulled from several different sources and I am trying to set it up in a way that related information to other bits of information. Following your suggestion (and the suggestions of others) I was able to clear the error, but wasn't able to get the data inserted into the new table. After executing the query, it returned 0 row(s) affected. Any idea on how to get the two pieces of data inserted together in the new table?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in `ON a.Name = b.Did` Name column may contains alphabets,number or special characters. Did column contains only number or integers only.

Comment: yes, the Name is a varchar that has both alphabets and numbers and the Did column is only an integer. I fixed that with Tab's suggestion but afterwards my insert isn't writing the data into the table like I want it to.